# How to refresh/keep alive the 'parent' session on a CAS server

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I am integrating against a CAS server. User logs into there, gets forwarded to a script which does the CAS validation, gets the User and logs them in. This all works fine.

Part of the spec for the integration is to ensure we ping the CAS server every 60 seconds, to ensure the user does not get logged out at the 'parent' CAS server, as they are still active.

Is there something built into the CAS setup for this purpose? I've been looking through the CAS documentation and the phpCAS client to no avail. There's a `renewAuthentication` method but it causes the user to have to login again when called. Perhaps this is just a configuraton issue at the server side though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to ping the CAS server on behalf of the user as your application *should not* have access to the token identifying the user's session.  The default policies automatically extend the user's single sign on session every time the user requests a new service ticket from the CAS server.

However, if you do have the TGT (which you really, really, really should avoid), you can basically request a service ticket for the user, and that would extend the life of the single sign on session (though if you did this, you would not need to do it every 60 seconds, as that's rather extreme).